# With protractor and TypeScript, how can I return the current page name from the URL as a string?

Tags: typescript, protractor

I'm having difficulty writing a function that will return the current page name from a URL in Protractor.  Here is the error that is presented in WebStorm.

> Error:(82, 28) TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value or consist of a single 'throw' statement.

To return the page name from the URL, if this were TypeScript, I'd write something like this.

```
public getPageName() : string {
    var path : string = browser.getCurrentUrl();
    if (path.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        path = path.split("?")[0]; // Strip the querystring.
    }
    return path.split("/").pop();
}
```

But since Protractor operates with Promises, I've written this.

```
public getPageName() : string {
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        if (url.indexOf("?") > -1) {
            url = url.split("?")[0]; // Strip the querystring.
        }
        return <string>url.split("/").pop();
    });
};
```

That `<string>` operation in angle brackets is my attempt at casting the return value to a string.  The only way that I can get around that error is to remove string from the function definition, like this.  But I want this to be strongly typed as a string.

```
public getPageName() {
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        if (url.indexOf("?") > -1) {
            url = url.split("?")[0]; // Strip the querystring.
        }
        return url.split("/").pop().toLowerCase();
    });
};
```

How can I return the page name and cast the return value as a string?  Thanks.

=== Updated 11/30/2015 ===

Based on Martin Vseticka's idea, I'm using the following code. This is in my spec.

```
import pageObject = require("../../pageObjects/myPage.pageObject");

describe('When performing X:', function() {
    var page = new pageObject.MyPageObjectClass();

    it('Should navigate to MyPage after clicking the add icon.', function () {
        element(by.css('.fa-plus')).click();
        page.getPageName().then(function(pageName){
            expect(pageName.toLowerCase() === "mypage").toBe(true);
        });
    });
    // Omitted code
}
```

And this is the getPageName function.

```
public getPageName()  {
    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
        if (url.indexOf("?") > -1) {
            url = url.split("?")[0]; // Strip the querystring.
        }
        return url.split("/").pop();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an **idea** how to solve your problem, I can't test it at the moment.

```
public getPageName():string {

    let result:string = null;

    browser.wait(function () {
        return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
            if (url.indexOf("?") > -1) {
                url = url.split("?")[0]; // Strip the querystring.
            }
            result = url.split("/").pop(); 
        });
    }, 10000, "URL wasn't obtained");

    return result;
}
```

http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait

Comment: Thanks Martin. That returns null.

Comment: Can you add some `console.log` commands to find out why it does not work? It seems that others tried similar approaches:  https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/610#issuecomment-37581578

Comment: Thanks. After adding some console.log statements, I can see that the function is assigning a value to result.  The sequence is that the "url" variable gets the URL. It successfully splits to remove the querystring from the URL, and then split/pop gets the page name.  But, it ends up returning null. Putting the return statement under result didn't fix it either. Also, the console shows "Error: URL wasn't obtained".  I also upped the wait timeout to 30 seconds, but it still timed out.  So this is close, but not yet working.